# Get upload Dir for an Image in a custom config - Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to retrieve the full URL of an uploaded image in the backend.

The code that creates the config for the upload:

```
<backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_image</backend_model> 
<upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">voucher/logo</upload_dir>
<base_url type="media" scope_info="1">voucher/logo</base_url>
```

but when i try to get it:

```
Mage::getBaseUrl('media').Mage::getStoreConfig('group/locale/module_logoimage',Mage::app()->getStore());
```

It won't give me the upload directory set in the system.xml(above)
I get: http://sample.com/media/default(scope)/image.png and it misses the voucher/logo part.
How can I get that from the config without reading the node?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Magento doesn't have a built in method for retrieving the `<upload_dir`.

If you look in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image` line 563:

```
 $baseDir = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseMediaPath();
```

Tracing this function to:

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Media_Config
```

It only does this:

```
return Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'product';
```

See this article from AlanStorm for more info (look in the comments section):
http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_configuration_in_depth_tutorial

**Update**

You can alternatively get the node's data using the following code:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()-> getConfig('path/to/node')
```